# How to use ConnectEx(mswsock.h) with RIO(Registered I/O)?

Tags: winsock, iocp, rio

I want to use RIO to get notifications from ConnectEx, but I didn't include RIOConnectEx in RIO_EXTIONS_FUNCTION_TABLE. I don't know how to get notifications about ConnectEx connections in RIODequeueCompletion.

I tried to connect OVERLAPPED to ConnectEx and get connection notifications via GetQueuedCompletionStatus, but RIO doesn't use OVERLAPPED and seems to get notifications via RIODequeueCompletion. Is there any way to get ConnectEx connection notifications from RIODequeueCompletion?

Comment: RIO used only for send and receive operations . so use `ConnectEx` direct as is. and then rio for send/receive

Comment: Thanks for the answer @RbMm, so I can't use asynchronous connect while using RIO?

Comment: Of course can. Use ConnectEx.